# How can I display a big double normally instead of scientifically normalized

Tags: c++, double, point, floating

I'm currently trying to make a simple calculator, but I want it to use somewhat big numbers(anything above 10^10 should do). And since any decent calculator has floating point operations, I decided to use double as my type. 
Sadly, when I tried to write a big number(around 10^7), it went into e notation.
I want to display it like a normal number.

All help is appreciated. :D

Comment: Also, `double` can carry more than 16 significant decimal digits, you should paste some code with your actual operations.

Comment: Simple float has its limit at 10^37 . You should have some other problem.

Comment: Maybe your printing function trims the decimals?

Comment: Correction, it doesn't do out of limits, rather it goes into E notation around 10^7. Sorry for the mistake >.<

Comment: @user3399371 And you dont want scientific notation?

Comment: No, I want a normal number up to around 10^15. Then I want it in notation, similar to how Windows' Calculator works.

Comment: @user3399371 I think you missunderstand something here. It stays a "normal" number. Consider `10^3 = 1000`, though represented in two ways, its the same number. Your question isnt about precision but about printing doubles/floats. So I advise you either to edit your question in order to make your intention clear or to delete it and create a new one stating your actual problem. Please dont forget to include your printing code.

Comment: -1 Please explain clearly in the question what the problem is. Show code, and as a clear and direct question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all digits of your double (instead of going into scientific notation), you have to change your output stream's float formatting to [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

[Live demo on Coliru:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d2caf6d2e335bd2)

```
double d = 1000000000000000.0; // 10^16
std::cout << std::fixed << d;
```

Output:

```
1000000000000000.000000
```

If you want your display to go into scientific notation at a custom exponent, you'll have to do that yourself using the existing tools.

Comment: If you believe this answer satisfies you, please consider accepting it by clicking the tick below the down arrow.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, too.
I'm kinda new to the site. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) library for for arbitrary precision arithmetic. If you're using it on Windows you can neatly install it using mingw-get.

For 64bit double you could use [long double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double), I think. I have personally never needed this.

And also there are processor extensions for longer floating point registers which I don't know much about and take a bit of effort to use for trivial tasks.